# Security test for .net desktop application: upload a file (shell) to check how software behaves

Tags: security-testing, desktop-application, security, .net, sql-injection

I am looking for a most common injection file (shell) to import my software to check if it is open to these kind of attacks or not. Any recommendation, web sites or blogs?

(summary: i will upload this file to my system and it will do some changes in the system)

Comment: Try asking the question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

A lot of stuff covered by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) applies to applications as the line between desktop app and web app blurs. Things like SQL injection, command injection, object injection to name a few injection attacks. I once tested a .Net MVC app by uploading a PHP file and tried to see if the code was executed or presented as raw text when viewed.

As far as tools you could try a free product like [Metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com/) but the learning curve is steep.